# Consider two i.i.d random variables $X$ and $Y$ with same PDF $f(x) = e^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

Question: Given two iid random variables $X$ and $Y$ with same PDF of $f(x) = e^{-x}$, $x>0$, find the PDF of $X+Y$ and $3X+2Y$. Are these two new PDF's independent?

What I've got so far:

First I defined $Z = X + Y$, since $x,y>0$, $z>0$. By applying a convolution on $X$ and $Y$ we get:
$f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} f_{XY}(x,z-x) \,dx \rightarrow f_Z(z) = \int_{0}^{z} e^{-x + x - z} \,dx \rightarrow f_Z(z) = ze^{-z}$.

Now for $W = 3X+2Y$, by also applying a convolution, we get:
$f_W(w) = \int_{0}^{w/3} f_{XY}(x,\dfrac{w-3x}{2}) \,dx \rightarrow f_W(w) = \int_{0}^{w/3} e^{(x-w)/2} \,dx \rightarrow f_W(w) = 2(e^{-w/3} - e^{-w/2})$.

However, when calculating the joint distribution of $Z$ and $W$ using the jacobian method, we get:

$|J| = 1$, $Y = 3Z-W$ and $X = W-2Z$, and thus:

$f_{WZ}(w,z) = f_{XY}(w-2z,3z-w) \rightarrow f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-(w-2z+3z-w)} \rightarrow f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-z} $

And so I concluded that the two new PDF's are not independent, because their joint probability is not equal to the product of the marginal probabilities. Are these results correct? Also, how can I get to $f_Z(z)$ from $f_{WZ}(w,z)$? Because I can't seem to figure out the right integration bounds in order to get the right marginal probabilities.

Comment: You are correct when you say $W$ and $Z$ are not independent.  But  $f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-z}$ looks improbable

Comment: But since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $f_{XY}$ is equal to the product of their respective PDF's right? When I multiply their PDF's together I get $f_{XY}(x,y) = e^{-(x+y)}$, and since $z=x+y$ this get's me the $f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-z}$. Maybe the convolutions aren't right then?

Comment: The reason I said $f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-z}$ looks improbable is that it does not obviously integrate to $1$ over $w$ and $z$.  Looking again I think you should have said  $f_{WZ}(w,z) = e^{-z}$ only  when $0 \le 2 z \le w \le 3z$, i.e. when $0 \le \frac w3  \le z \le \frac w2$, and  $f_{WZ}(w,z)=0$ otherwise.  This does integrate to $1$, and shows why $W$ and $Z$ are not independent: the value of one severely constrains the possible value of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the pdf of $3X + 2Y$. You are missing factor of $\frac{1}{2}$. It should be,

$ \displaystyle f_W(w) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{w/3} f_{XY}\left(x,\dfrac{w-3x}{2}\right) \, dx$

$ \displaystyle = \int_{0}^{w/3} e^{(x-w)/2} \,dx  = (e^{-w/3} - e^{-w/2})$

You are right that as $ \ f_{WZ} (W, Z) \ne f_W (w) \cdot f_Z (z)$, $W$ and $Z$ are not independent.

Comment: Why exactly is that? I don't understand why I should multiply the integral by $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: you can check it using Jacobian method or see it this way - $\displaystyle F_W(w) = \int_{0}^{w/3} F_Y\left(\dfrac{w-3x}{2}\right) \, f_X(x) \, dx$
Differentiating, $\displaystyle f_W(w) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{w/3} f_Y\left(\dfrac{w-3x}{2}\right) \, f_X(x) \, dx$

Comment: As a validation step, try and integrate your pdf for $0 \leq w \leq \infty$